# What's the meaning of bounding a trait by its own generic lifetime (trait Bar<'a>: 'a)?

Tags: generics, rust, traits, lifetime

I've seen this kind of code in [the official reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes):

```
trait Bar<'a>: 'a { }
```

I haven't thought of this kind of case.

I intuitively interpret "lifetime bound" of a type as follows:

```
some_reference: &'a Some_Type = &instance_of_Some_Type;
T: 'a // T is borrowed by "instance_of_Some_Type"
```

What's the meaning of `trait Bar<'a>: 'a { }` — there's a method which uses a parameter borrowing the type?

Is it the same as this?

```
impl Bar<'a> for Another_Type
where
    Another_Type: 'a
{
}
```

I can't think of the usage of above implication, what is an example usage of this case? I'm having a hard time getting the meaning of "lifetime parameter of a trait".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lifetime bound on a trait is about references inside some type that implements that trait.

For example, a `'static` lifetime bound on a trait means it can't be implemented by any structs that contain references that don't outlive `'static`.

Let's take your example without the lifetime bound:

```
trait Bar<'a> { }
```

This is a parameterized trait based on a lifetime `'a`, but there is no requirement that an implementation of this actually outlives `'a`, so we could do something like:

```
struct HasRef<'b>(&'b i32);
impl Bar<'static> for HasRef<'_> { }
```

which says that *any* `HasRef` struct - even one with a very short lifetime - implements the `Bar<'static>` trait.

Writing instead

```
trait Bar<'a>: 'a { }
```

says that any type implementing `Bar<'a>` must live at least as long as `'a`, which probably makes more sense.

(These bounds are important especially for trait objects (with type like `dyn Trait`), since only the trait itself can the compiler about the lifetime of references inside this trait object.)

Comment: Aha. I could elide lifetime bound for ```dyn Trait``` by implementing lifetimebound directly into the ```Trait```! Thanks.

Comment: However, it's quite fuzzy to me. (Whole bunch of lifetime stuffes....)